# How to pass select from one controller to another in Zend?

Tags: zend-framework

currently I'm using an output controller for simple HTML outputs. There is another report controller for output as PDF. Both controllers use the same SQL and are filtered by session data.

Is there a way to pass the Zend_Select object from the list controller to the report controller? So I don't have to assemble the select in each controller again.

As I remember it's not possible with the registry. But maybe there exists another elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use smth like a abstract base controller for the list and report controller, that would be helpful.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10570507)

Comment: @ineersa sry for the wrong answer but for these feature, you need min 50 Reputation and i had at the time when i wrote the answer only 46 Reputation. so it was not allowed for me.